# How to change transitive version of gradle dependency?

Tags: spring, hibernate, gradle, kotlin

I have a gradle multimodule project. I need to use precise version of hibernate.

In the repository module a added

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.15.RELEASE") {
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
}
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.2.15.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.15.Final"
```

(spring boot 1.5.15.RELEASE uses hibernate 5.0.12.Final)

I have the following hierarchy of modules

```
+--controller
  + --service
    + --repository
```

And it seems that service module uses hibernate 5.0.12.Final.

I found information about *configurations.all*, but it's impossible to exclude particular version of dependency.

Is there a way of using hibernate 4.2.15.Final in all modules?

Comment: did you try to configure the dependecy resolver rules, as described here  ? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot with Gradle you are also using the Spring Boot plugin (and with that the dependency plugin). Just specify the version of hibernate you want to use as explained in the Spring BOot reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.15.RELEASE')
    implementation ('org.hibernate:hibernate-core') {
        version {
            strictly '4.2.15.Final'
        }
    }
    implementation ('org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager') {
        version {
            strictly '4.2.15.Final'
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html